# The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: server, apache2, .htaccess

A question asked many times and yet I didn't find an answer that helped me.

I have an Apache Server running under Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (yes I need to update).

I have a webpage in `/var/www/website/index.html`

I have set the Domain Forward at my providers to
`https://ip.address/website/index.hmtl`

I have a `.htaccess` file in `/home/website/` which reads

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Options Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html       
order deny,allow
```

I have added a
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
into my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

When trying to visit the site, I get the error `The requested URL /website/index.html was not found on this server.`

This is the first time I'm doing something like this and I'm completely at loss... Why can't I visit my Page?

UPDATE:
I now set up everything as in https://debian-administration.org/article/412/Hosting_multiple_websites_with_Apache2

Now I get the error that my browser can't get a connection to the server?

UPDATE2:
I now have an `error.log` file in my website's directory saying
`[Wed Dec 07 08:23:10 2016] [error] (2)No such file or directory: could not open transfer log file /home/www/website/logs/access.log.`

Comment: @Terrance There is no `000-default.conf`... only a `000-default` and there is `DocumentRoot /var/www` Hm I think thats not right, right?

Comment: @Terrance ok, but that kind of means that I only can run one website per server?

Comment: @Terrance It didnt help either... :D

Comment: @Terrance permissions are alright. Could it be my SSL certificates? They could be quite old... How would I check that and/or update them?

Comment: Here's info for multiple websites:  https://debian-administration.org/article/412/Hosting_multiple_websites_with_Apache2

Comment: @Terrance Ok now i have `DocumentRoot /var/www` and put my folder `website` in `/var/www/website` and changed my forwarding to `http://85.25.108.30/website/index.html`.. It still doesnt work

Comment: @Terrance Still doesn't work. Thank you for your help though. Maybe I just reset the whole server. Upgrade it on the way...

Comment: @Terrance In Ubuntu 12.04, the default document root is `/var/www`. It was changed to `/var/www/html` when Apache got upgraded to 2.4 in Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: @Dan It doesn't matter.  OP can't get it working if it is in /var/www or /var/www/html.

Comment: @Dan It is both not working :( I now set it up like the Link Terrance gave, and now I have a different error :D

Answer (score 7):

On ubuntu enabling module rewrite by running 
`sudo a2enmod rewrite`
and then retart apache2 service with 
`service apache2 restart` will solve your problem

Comment: uh, a necromancer! Thank you for that, I will definitely try that out. At the moment, I run the websites with my Raspberry since they are still not in a shape to go online (where is all my time going??)...

Comment: Thanks bilal you saved my life